# Format number as currency in a MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I found in a forum and have retrofitted for my application. It displays a table of closing costs in a `MsgBox`. I would like to format the numeric values as currency but do not know where or how in the code to do this. I have used the following code in the past to format a variable to currency but do not really know how to apply in my code.

Here is what I have used that works to format to currency:

```
FormattedClosingVolume = Format(ClosingVolume, "#,##0")
```

Here is that code that I am using and for the `MsgBox`; I want to format column `AO` to currency to be displayed in the `MsgBox`.

```
Sub Closing_Costs_Popup()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
        xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
        xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If
    'Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Closing Costs").Range("AO2:AP39")
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    For xRow = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        For xCol = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
            xStr = xStr & vbTab & xRg.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value '& vbTab
        Next
        xStr = xStr & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox xStr, vbInformation, "Settlement Charges"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim n As Double, s As String
    n = 1234.56
    s = Format(n, "$#,##0.00")
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To apply this in your code, something like:

```
xStr = xStr & vbTab & xRg.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value
```

would be replaced by:

```
xStr = xStr & vbTab & Format(xRg.Cells(xRow, xCol).Value, "$#,##0.00")
```

*(untested)*

Comment: @MEC  See my **EDIT#1**